# Custom Font Radio Button not detecting click

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I made a Custom Radio button with custom font. Here is the code to the Radio Button:

```
public class AvenirRadioButton extends RadioButton {

    /*
     * Caches typefaces based on their file path and name, so that they don't have to be created every time when they are referenced.
     */
    private static Typeface mTypeface;

    public AvenirRadioButton(final Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public AvenirRadioButton(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public AvenirRadioButton(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs, final int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

        if (mTypeface == null) {
            mTypeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/avenir_light.ttf");
        }
        setTypeface(mTypeface);
    }

}
```

**Here is the layout usage:**

```
                     <RadioGroup
                        android:id="@+id/radioGroupType"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <com.app.utils.AvenirRadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/radioProject"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/radio_selector"
                            android:button="@null"
                            android:checked="true"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/size_small"
                            android:paddingTop="@dimen/size_small"
                            android:text="@string/project"
                            android:textColor="@drawable/radio_text_selector"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />

                        <com.app.utils.AvenirRadioButton
                            android:id="@+id/radioSocial"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_weight="1"
                            android:background="@drawable/radio_selector"
                            android:button="@null"
                            android:gravity="center"
                            android:paddingBottom="@dimen/size_small"
                            android:paddingTop="@dimen/size_small"
                            android:text="@string/social"
                            android:textColor="@drawable/radio_text_selector"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </RadioGroup>
```

**The radio_text_selector:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:color="@color/white" android:state_checked="true" />
    <item android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />

</selector>
```

**The radio_selector:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />

            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_checked="false">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/white" />

            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/colorPrimary" />
        </shape>
    </item>

</selector>
```

The problem is the Radio button in not checkable when I add the font. I mean if I use RadioButton instead of AvenirRadioButton, check happens. Is there anything I can do to keep the font and check both?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you even comment typeface related logics in your custom class, it won't work as a standard `RadioButton` does, because you have incorrectly overriden the constructor, that creates a Java object from `xml`:

```
public AvenirRadioButton(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, R.attr.radioButtonStyle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to change the font then, instead of creating custom radiobutton, following code can be used:

```
RadioButton rb  = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.radioSocial);
Typeface font = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/avenir_light.ttf");
rb.setTypeface(font);
```